# Android - Display Progress Dialog on button click ONLY if AsyncTask has not completed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am building an OCR Android application that performs many image processing tasks in the background which takes some time to complete. 
The steps it performs are as follows:

1. Capture image
2. Display image to user, provide option to recapture the image or proceed
3. Display processed image, provide option to recapture the image or proceed.
4. Extract text

These tasks are time consuming and I would like to reduce some time by starting the next task as soon as the the previous finishes, while displaying the progress dialog "Please wait" only if the user clicks the proceed button and the task has not completed.

I am wondering is this possible and if so how do I achieve this?

Below is my code for the OCR task:

```
private class OCRTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public OCRTask(PreviewActivity activity) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String path = previewFilePath;

        String ocrText;

        OCR ocr = new OCR();
        ocrText = ocr.OCRImage(path, PreviewActivity.this);

        // Write the result to a txt file and store it in the same dir as the temp img
        // find the last occurence of '/'
        int p=previewFilePath.lastIndexOf("/");
        // e is the string value after the last occurence of '/'
        String e=previewFilePath.substring(p+1);
        // split the string at the value of e to remove the it from the string and get the dir path
        String[] a = previewFilePath.split(e);
        String dirPath = a[0];

        String fileString = dirPath + "ocrtext.txt";
        File file = new File(fileString);

        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(ocrText);

            bw.close();
            System.out.println("done!!");

        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

        new WordCorrect(fileString);

        return ocrText;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Set the progress dialog attributes
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Extracting text...");
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();


        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(PreviewActivity.this, ReceiptEditActivity.class);
        // Pass the file path and text result to the receipt edit activity
        i.putExtra(FILE_PATH, previewFilePath);
        Log.e("OCR TEXT: ", result);
        i.putExtra(OCR_TEXT, result);
        // Start receipt edit activity
        PreviewActivity.this.startActivityForResult(i, 111);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take one boolean variable inside your Activity or Fragment, like

```
public static boolean isTaskRunning = false;
```

and inside **onPreExecute()** of AsyncTask, change its value to true.

```
YourActivity.isTaskRunning = true;
```

I am considering that you have taken this variable in activity class. And inside onPostExecute(String result), revert its value to false

```
YourActivity.isTaskRunning = false;
```

Now, on button click, check for this variable value, if its **true** then show your **progress dialog** otherwise not.